# Java Regex with collon

Tags: java, regex

I want to match below string

RegEx I'm trying:

```
{1:F21XXXXXXXX9999123456}{4:{177:1007300\\d{2}8}{451:0}{108:XXX190876234-1}}

{1:F21XXXXXXXX9999123456}{4:{177:1007300\\d+
```

String to match:

```
{1:F21XXXXXXXX9999123456}{4:{177:1007300838}{451:0}{108:XXX190876234-1}}
```

I tried other ways as well but facing issues in matching any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Escape every `{}`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xxs0c6/1). It would be useful to include your java code

Comment: thanks @ThomasAyoub

Comment: @PatrickParker Thanks for pointing out. `**` don't belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regexp (with missing escapes) is:

`\{1:F21XXXXXXXX9999123456\}\{4:\{177:1007300\d{2}8\}\{451:0\}\{108:XXX190876234-1\}\}`

When written as a Java String literal:

```
Pattern.compile("\\{1:F21XXXXXXXX9999123456\\}\\{4:\\{177:1007300\\d{2}8\\}\\{451:0\\}\\{108:XXX190876234-1\\}\\}");
```